# Unable to install LINQtoCSV in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to use the LinqtoCSV library in my Silverlight application. But when I try to "Install-Package LinqToCsv" from the package manager, I get the below error:

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'LINQtoCSV'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  LinqToCsv
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],    InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

This works in my WPF project, just not my Silverlight project. Is it possible to use LinqtoCSV in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, it is not possible to use `LinqtoCSV` in Silverlight.

To run `LinqtoCSV`, you need to have the .NET 4.0 framework installed.

Silverlight is a subset of the .Net framework and would not be able to run this library.

Reference: [LINQ to CSV library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library) (Read the requirements)